# How do I know if a garment is considered tights or leggings or pants?

Tags: tznius-modesty

Using the Shulchan Aruch as a guide how can we deduce where womens' leg wear crosses from being considered  tights to being considered leggings to being considered pants. Is there a decision algorithm that we can come up with?

Comment: For men or for women? למאי נפקא מינה?

Comment: I am asking about women.

Comment: And are these women wearing a skirt as well? You’re assuming there is some kind of halachic difference between these three types of leg wear. Probably worth spelling out what that is

Comment: @ Joel K Yes, the women are wearing skirts that are way below the knees.

Comment: Hi Mars. To the best of my knowledge, Shulchan Aruch never mentions the words "pants" "leggings" or "tights". Does that answer your question?

Comment: @Double AA LOL. So how do rabbonim decide tights are okay and leggings and pants are not? There gotta be some template they are using.

Comment: Hardly. Those are not well defined halachic terms and they have no traditional formal Jewish definition. Anyone who tells you otherwise is just making things up.

Comment: @MarsSojourner tights usually have fabric covering the feet, while pants and leggings usually end at the ankle or higher. That is a practical/cultural difference though.

Comment: The Shulchan Aruch can't cover every kind of clothing everywhere invented. So it is the job of the Rabbis to determine which clothes are ok and which are not following general principles. And many communities will have their own standard above and beyond the minimum of the Shulchan Aruch.